# How to change this terminal customization tutorial for usage in zsh rather than bash?

Tags: terminal, bash, zsh, customization

[This tutorial](https://medium.com/@charlesdobson/how-to-customize-your-macos-terminal-7cce5823006e) gives instructions on how to customize the look of macOS's Terminal application. I followed the instructions but used `zsh` where it said `bash` in hopes that it would work, but it didn't. I changed the shell to Bash to see how it would work, and it did, but I need to use zsh for work purposes. Is there a way to adapt the tutorial for use in zsh rather than Bash, or is there a tutorial for customizing your zsh shell?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to adapt the tutorial for use in zsh rather than Bash,

No, not really. Customizing Zsh is fairly different from customizing Bash. It would be quite a lot of work.

> or is there a tutorial for customizing your zsh shell?

Yes, there is!  There’s quite a few of them, in fact, but I found this one by far the best: https://scriptingosx.com/2019/06/moving-to-zsh/

However, instead of doing everything by hand, you might just want to copy-paste an existing config to get you started quickly. Here’s one I’ve been working on, with input from the Zsh development group, which has *zero external dependencies,* and thus should work out of the box for any Zsh installation: https://gitlab.com/marlonrichert/zsh-sensible/-/blob/master/zshrc

Just save that as `~/.zshrc` and restart your shell. Please try it out and let me know what you think. Ideas for improvement are welcome.

Comment: I'll try that and tell you how it works. Thanks! I'll accept the answer then!

Comment: Thanks! I am using both, alternating when I feel like it. Yours is great and so is Oh My Zsh.